# How to create and test a SOAP and HTTP web service in Java, Maven, and Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, maven, soap

Essentially I am trying to create a simple SOAP Webservice in Java, Maven, and Spring.
I have tried following tutorials, books, and just hacking at it. Can anyone help please.

**Background**

- We have a project which is effectively a bunch of libraries boiling
  to a handful of interfaces.
- The project is a maven project created using the spring framework,
  mainly roo.
- We're running the STS eclipse IDE which has a vmware (vSphere)
  virtual web server.

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- Add web services for SOAP and HTTP endpoints.
- Have existing WSDLs for these web services.

**What I have tried:**

**1. Creating a web service with "Top down Java bean Web Service" type pointing to the wsdl, VMware server.**

- Creates a web service project separate from my existing project.
- Web Service seems to be synchronised in the virtual web server.
- Right clicking to the home page for the web server results in the 404 error.
- Looking at the localhost:8080 shows a running virtual web server page.

*Problems:*

- Project created is in the eclipse workspace rather than the source folders. This results in source control commitment issues.
- Is it normal for all web services to be a separate project per web service in eclipse?
- Right clicking to the home page for the web server results in the 404 error.
- Not sure how to debug the 404 error to determine the issue.

**2. Created an SomeNameEndpoint.java file and generated a web service project from this.**

- Creates a web service project separate from my existing project.
- Web Service seems to be synchronised in the virtual web server.
- Right clicking to the home page for the web server results in the 404 error.
- Looking at the localhost:8080 shows a running virtual web server page.

  ```
  package shlonline.integration.endpoints;

  import javax.jws.WebMethod;
  import javax.jws.WebService;

  import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

  @WebService(serviceName = "myServiceName")
  public class myServiceEndPoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport
  {
      @WebMethod
      public boolean runWebMethod(String input)
      {
          return false;
      }
  }
  ```

*Problems:*

- Right clicking to the home page for the web server results in the 404 error.
- Not sure how to debug the 404 error to determine the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial along was really helpful for me, the project is available for github download, and uses maven and spring web services. It uses spring-ws with spring annotations of @Endpoint and @PayloadRoot annotations rather than the @WebService you have above.

http://briansjavablog.blogspot.com/2013/01/spring-web-services-tutorial.html

Comment: There is now an updated version of this post using CXF with full working source code. http://briansjavablog.blogspot.co.uk/2016/10/apache-cxf-contract-first-web-service.html